# how to get filepath from JavaFX WebView?

Tags: java, security, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

I need to get the full filepath of the user's selected file.

HTML

```
<input name="attachFiles" id="attachFiles" type="file"/>
```

Java

```
HTMLInputElement attachFiles = WebMisc.getHTMLInputElement(webEngine, "attachFiles");
final String filename = attachFiles.getValue();
```

However, filename is always C:\fakepath\<file name>

How do I get the real full filepath?

This is used for a web-looking UI. All the real work is still done by myself, not the WebEngine.